# Visio drawing scale with glues on drop

Tags: vba, visio

I have a stencil where one master is a group, where each sub-shape is glued to another sub-shape.  When the master is dropped on the page, I ungroup it, leaving the sub-shapes glued to one another such that one shape is the leader for positioning and all others follow it.

This works fine at the 1:1 scale, but it gets very screwy when the drawing scale changes.  When I drop the master onto a scaled page, the positioning of the glued sub-shapes is visually incorrect.

When the sub-shapes get glued together, I see that the follower shape's PinX and PinY formulae get set by Visio to something like:
PNTY(LOCTOPAR(PNT(Sheet.1!Connections.X1,Sheet.1!Connections.Y1),Sheet.1!EventXFMod,EventXFMod))+-0.3125 in

So my thought is that the '+-0.3125 in' is what's screwing up with the scaling.  The '0.3125 in' should be multiplied by a scaling factor to keep the positioning consistent for the scaled page, but it is not.

When I modify the equation manually to multiply the spacing by the scale factor, the positioning is fine but then Visio doesn't consider the shapes glued anymore.

Is there some behavior I can change that will make Visio behave the way I want with scaled pages?

Comment: Hope this article by [David J Parker](http://visiorules.com/visinfo/About.cshtml) can help: [Anchoring scaled shapes to page corners in #Visio](http://Anchoring%20scaled%20shapes%20to%20page%20corners%20in%20#Visio)

Comment: Correct link for article is [Anchoring scaled shapes to page corners in #Visio](https://blog.bvisual.net/2017/08/09/anchoring-scaled-shapes-to-page-corners-in-visio/)